# How to build a clock?

Tags: time, probability

You have unreliable clocks that fire in the interval $(t,t+\delta)$ with probability density $f(t;\lambda)=\lambda\exp(-\lambda x)$. How will you build *the best* clock using these unreliable components to measure time $T (\gg \lambda) $?

1. You can use as many unreliable clocks you want
2. You can do any computation using circuits
3. However the circuits must asynchronous i.e. - you can't use any clock other than the ones given.

The best clock to measure time $T$ is one which is *expected* to fire at time $T$ with *least variance*

[EDIT: I am not necessarily looking for the solution, but for suggestions for directions. So feel free to advice.]

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use an even number of clocks! (for those missing out, there's a famous engineering rule that if you're going to have redundant systems, make sure there's a tie-breaker, so two clocks disagreeing leaves you with no info, while three clocks lets you pick the two  of three which agree :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best" if you can use as many as you want. You can keep improving accuracy by adding more "basic" exponentially-distributed firing time clocks to your timepiece machine. I don't know whether there is a best *given a certain number* of allowed basic clocks, but if this is a homework problem then I'm guessing it's aimed at making you think about one of or both of two things:

1. [The laws of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) OR
2. [The central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

To illustrate the first, imagine you have a large ensemble of basic clocks. Suppose you have $N$ of them: you "initialise" them all at once and then suppose your circuitry can let you know how many have fired at any given time. You now have a dial that ticks up from $0$ to $N$ over a time lasting of the order of several $\lambda^{-1}$. At any time $t$ after initialisation, what is the probability distribution of the position on your dial? Well, the probability that any given basic clock has fired is:

$$p(t) = \lambda\,\int_0^t \,e^{-\lambda\,u}\,\,\mathrm{d}\,u=1-e^{-\lambda\,t}$$

So, given all the firing times are independent and identically distributed random variables, the dial's position at time $t$ is the following binomial distribution:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}\mathrm{Pr}(X=x\in\{0,\,1,\,2,\,\cdots,\,N\}) &=& \binom{N}{x}\, p(t)^x\,(1-p(t))^{N-x}\\ &=& \binom{N}{x} e^{-\lambda\,N\,t}\,e^{\lambda\,x\,t}(1-e^{-\lambda\,\,t})^x\end{array}$$

Now, the normal approximation to the binomial holds as $N\to\infty$, so if we choose big enough $N$, this random variable is Gaussian with mean $N\,p(t)=N-N\,e^{-\lambda\,t}$ and standard deviation $\sigma= \sqrt{N\,(e^{-\lambda\,t}-\,e^{-2\,\lambda\,t})}$.

So, for example, you could make one "tick" when your ensemble reaches $1-e$ of the population fired: the mean tick interval will be $t=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and (you'll need to delve into the details of the calculation here) the proportional variation of your tick interval will be of the order of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$. So you can make your tick interval more accurate by adding more basic clocks.

To illustrate the second method - using the central limit theorem - you run one basic clock a large number of times and define one "tick" interval to be the time it takes for your clock to fire $N$ times in series. Again, the sum of the firing intervals, being a sum of identically, independently distributed random variables, will converge to a Gaussian random variable with a mean of $\frac{N}{\lambda}$ and standard deviation $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\lambda}$. So again, the proportional error in your tick interval will be of the order of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, which you can make as small as you like by increasing $N$.